# Арифметические операции с несколькими DataFrame с неупорядоченными именами столбцов и значений индексов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть на входе несколько DataFrame разных форматов, примеры приведены ниже:

Пример:

```
Год   com1 com2 com3 com4 com5
2012    5   11    2    7    7
2013    6   10    5    8    4
2014    7    8    6    9    5
2015    8    9    8    9    5
2016    4    4    4    4    2


Год com3    com2    com1    com5    com4
2015    5   11  2   7   7
2012    6   10  5   8   4
2013    7   8   6   9   5
2014    8   9   8   9   5
2016    4   4   4   4   2
```

Исходник: https://dropmefiles.com/9eLlv
То есть второй таблице уже изменен порядок данных(и столбцы, и строки). Нужно получить новый DataFrame по каждому значению и каждому году. Для примера: DF4= DF1+DF2+DF3

т.е. на выходе хочу получить нечто такое:

`com1  com2  com3  com4 com5
2012     20 27 16 16 19`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала читаем все листы из Excel файла в словарь состоящий из DataFrame's:

```
In [325]: dfs = pd.read_excel(r'C:\download\sm.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

получим:

```
In [326]: dfs.keys()
Out[326]: odict_keys(['Лист1', 'Лист2', 'Лист3'])

In [327]: dfs.values()
Out[327]:
odict_values([      com1  com2  com3  com4  com5
2012     5    11     2     7     7
2013     6    10     5     8     4
2014     7     8     6     9     5
2015     8     9     8     9     5
2016     4     4     4     4     2,       com3  com2  com1  com5  com4
2015     5    11     2     7     7
2012     6    10     5     8     4
2013     7     8     6     9     5
2014     8     9     8     9     5
2016     4     4     4     4     2,       com2  com1  com4  com3  com5
2013     5    11     2     7     7
2012     6    10     5     8     4
2014     7     8     6     9     5
2015     8     9     8     9     5
2016     4     4     4     4     2])
```

суммируем данные всех листов - выравнивание по именам столбцов и по значениям индексов Pandas сделает автоматически:

```
In [328]: d4 = sum(dfs.values())

In [329]: d4
Out[329]:
      com1  com2  com3  com4  com5
2012    20    27    16    16    19
2013    23    23    19    15    20
2014    23    24    23    20    19
2015    19    28    22    24    17
2016    12    12    12    10     8
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [330]: d4 = dfs['Лист1'] / (dfs['Лист2'] + dfs['Лист3'])

In [331]: d4
Out[331]:
          com1      com2      com3      com4      com5
2012  0.333333  0.687500  0.142857  0.777778  0.583333
2013  0.352941  0.769231  0.357143  1.142857  0.250000
2014  0.437500  0.500000  0.352941  0.818182  0.357143
2015  0.727273  0.473684  0.571429  0.600000  0.416667
2016  0.500000  0.500000  0.500000  0.666667  0.333333
```

Comment: 1. Когда мы считали все листы в словарь, как потом к каждому из них обратиться в отдельности?
2. Функция суммирования автоматически распознает элементы, а если мне необходимо сложные операции провести? Умножить первый на второй и вычесть третий , например?

Comment: @Max, это как раз то что я делал в предыдущем вопросе... ;)

Comment: Все, понял. Благодарю.